# onreadystatechange event problem in AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

The problem seems very strange. I have a AJAX helper function within a same aspx file and onreadystatechange  event is handled like this

```
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
                   //do some opp
      }
```

this works fine. i can read the xmlhttp value inside the callback.

And i **moved the AJAX helper methods to addition js file**. And i have created a method something like this

```
   function AjaxHelper() {
       this.GetValue = function(sData, sMethod, assembly, json, aSyncfunction) {
          var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

         if (typeof(aSyncfunction) != "undefined" && aSyncfunction != null) {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = aSyncfunction
         }

         //Ajax open and send code here

       }
   }
```

Now i create a callback function in my aspx file and called the AjaxHelper.GetValue() function

```
     var callback=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
                   //do some opp

     }

     AjaxHelper.GetValue("test","getTest()","UIhelper","",callback)
```

And the callback function is suceesfully called everytime after the state changes, but i cant reference the xmlhttp variable. **its always undefined**.

I though its going to execute in the AJaxhelper context, but its not.

Can anybody calrify me how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I though its going to execute in the AJaxhelper context, but its not.

No. JavaScript is lexically scoped. Once you finish the function `GetValue`, the local variable `xmlhttp` is no longer accessible. If there are no closures inside the function's scope retaining a reference to `xmlhttp`, as in this case there aren't, the variable `xmlhttp` is gone forever.

You might want to have a closure retain `xmlhttp` in `GetValue` and pass it to the callback function:

```
if (aSyncfunction) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
        aSyncfunction(xmlhttp);
    };
}
```

Or you could assign the object to a member variable like `this.xmlhttp` where it will be visible to other functions inside and outside the object.

PS. also caution, JavaScript is case-sensitive:

> var xml​**H**​ttp

Comment: thanks bobince for ur response. have a doubt. "aSyncfunction.apply(this)" wont work??

Comment: It will work if `this` is correct. If you already lost the object reference by pulling a method off its owner object and passing it to an `onsomething` event handler or a `Timeout`, `this` won't be what you expect and passing it to the function won't do any good.